# Why Twilio Flex HOLD MUSIC TWIML played after 25 to 30 seconds In case of Call transfer from watson assistant

Tags: watson-assistant, twilio-flex, twilio-node

I am calling Twilio number from Watson dialog using watson vgwActTransfer.
At Twilio side I am receiving incoming call using Studio flow.
Here I have used SendToFlex widget. Where call will be queued in Queue 1 for 30 seconds.

While call is Queue 1, hold music is not played for end user for almost 25 seconds then music starts.
I am not sure what is problem. I can see task waiting in queue but no hold music played for user till 25s.

I tried playing text using Say/Play widget, but that also seems playing from 3rd line onwards after waiting for few seconds. First 2 lines are not played to user.

This problem I am facing for both Twilio default hold music as well as my custom music.